# First Come First Serve Wait Time Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, scheduling

As i understand FCFS does not need any sorting but there are no examples covered in the internet what happens if waiting time goes negative?

So i understand that algorithm for waiting time is: WT = CT (Completion Time) - AT (Arrival Time) - BT (Burst Time).
But what happens if i have:

```
AT: 0 / BT: 2
AT: 0 / BT: 4
AT: 15 / BT: 5
AT: 21 / BT: 10
```

My calculations would be:

```
WT = 2 - 0 - 2 = 0
WT = 6 - 0 - 4 = 2
WT = 11 - 15 -5 = -9
WT = 21 - 21 - 10 = -10
Avg: (0+2-10-9)/4 = -17/4  = -4,25 (seems unreal)
```

Is the correct answer negative or should i modify the algorithm somehow?

Comment: How can you have an arrival time of 15 and completion time of 11 when you start your time at 0?

Comment: Doesen't a completion time add up from 2+4+5?

Comment: Since the burst time is the amount of CPU time the process gets when it is scheduled, the TOTAL burst time should be less than or equal to the difference of your completion and arrival time. It shouldn't be negative.

Comment: The formula is correct. A negative wait time implies a start time prior to the arrival. Your completion times are suspect.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? I don't quite understand what do you mean (what i'm saying is that could you show with an example?).

Comment: [This may help](http://web.cs.wpi.edu/~claypool/courses/3013-A00/slides/sched.pdf). Your math is just wrong. In your example, in FCFS an AT of 15 with BT of 5 will have a CT of 20 unless a situation like your first two processes occurred.

Comment: So as i understand, third and fourth WT should be 0, because they don't have to wait?

Comment: @charen Yes! That is correct.